# Netbeans 6.5 Diff Tool

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, diff, netbeans6.5

I'm very happy of Netbeans 6.5 diff tool, I have to ask some questions about it:

- which is its name?
- there's an equivalent for eclipse?
- is there any standalone version (without netbeans)?

Thank you very much!!

Valerio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some info about the [Netbeans diff tool](http://diff.netbeans.org/). It is part of the support modules for Netbeans version control.  Here is a [link](http://www.netbeans.org/source/browse/versioncontrol/#dirlist) to the Netbeans source code for its version control modules.

Comment: thanks! I think there will be neither stand alone or eclipse version!

Comment: There are eclipse plug-ins for version control support, the subversion plug-in is http://subclipse.tigris.org/ .  Subclipse supports visual diffs.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) includes a visual diff/merge tool (TortoiseMerge) which is very nice. As a bonus, you can diff images, for example the application UI, using TortoiseIDiff. TortoiseSVN integrates Subversion with the (Windows) desktop.